# Function to Highlight Specific Cells Multiple Times In Loop

Tags: excel, vba, function

Currently I am calling each specific cell asking for them to change the cell color to be yellow, is there a function that I can write that calls each of these cells to be highlighted? Here is my code. I have a lot of variables that are defined in other subs and not in this one if there is a variable does not appear to be defined.

I also have a long if statement below that has repeating lines of code, but I am not sure I can make those into a function since they all equal different values

```
 Global sysrow As Integer, sysnum As String, specmin As Integer, specmax As Integer, formula As Integer, wsName As String
 Global coherencelengrow As Integer, tunrangerow As Integer, averagepowerrow As Integer, sweeprterow As Integer, kclockctrow As Integer, kclockdepthrow As Integer, kclockjitter As Integer, scopefile As Integer, spectrogramdir As Integer, snapdownvol As Integer
 Global coherencelength As Integer, tuningrange As Integer, power As Integer, sweeprate As Integer, kclockcount As Integer, kclockdepth As Integer

 Sub updateWD() 
 Dim tuningr As Range, filename As String, spectro_directory As String, percentvol As Variant

 Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(coherencelengrow, specmin) = coherencelength
 Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(coherencelengrow, specmin).Interior.Color = vbYellow
 For Each tuningr In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500").Cells ' for loop needed to prevent from skipping over second row of wavelenght tuning range
    If tuningr.value = "Wavelength Range" Then
    tuningr(1, 3).value = tuningrange 
    tuningr(1, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
 Next tuningr
 Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(averagepowerrow, specmin) = power
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(averagepowerrow, specmin).Interior.Color = vbYellow
 Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(kclockdepthrow, specmin) = kclockdepth
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(kclockdepthrow, specmin).Interior.Color = vbYellow
 Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(kclockjitter, specmin) = kclockcount
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(kclockjitter, specmin).Interior.Color = vbYellow
 Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(kclockctrow, specmin) = kclockcount
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(kclockctrow, specmin).Interior.Color = vbYellow
 Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(sweeprterow, specmin) = sweeprate
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(sweeprterow, specmin).Interior.Color = vbYellow

 If wsName = "AXP-3" And sweeprate < 50 Then
    For Each percentvol In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500").Cells
        If percentvol.value = "Percent Snapdown Voltage" Then
        percentvol(1, 5).value = "95"
        percentvol(1, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next percentvol
 ElseIf wsName = "AXP-3" And sweeprate = 50 Then
  filename = "Test_50-3"
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(scopefile, formula) = filename
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(scopefile, formula).Interior.Color = vbYellow
spectro_directory = "Test_50-3_spectrogram.set"
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(spectrogramdir, formula) = spectro_directory
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(spectrogramdir, formula).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    For Each percentvol In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500").Cells
    If percentvol.value = "Percent Snapdown Voltage" Then
        percentvol(1, 5).value = "98"
        percentvol(1, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next percentvol
 ElseIf wsName = "AXP-3" And sweeprate = 100 Then
filename = "Test_100-3"
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(scopefile, formula) = filename
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(scopefile, formula).Interior.Color = vbYellow
spectro_directory = "Test_100-3_spectrogram.set"
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(spectrogramdir, formula) = spectro_directory
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(spectrogramdir, formula).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    For Each percentvol In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500").Cells
    If percentvol.value = "Percent Snapdown Voltage" Then
        percentvol(1, 5).value = "110"
        percentvol(1, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next percentvol
 ElseIf wsName = "AXP-3" And sweeprate = 200 Then
filename = "Test_200-3"
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(scopefile, formula) = filename
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(scopefile, formula).Interior.Color = vbYellow
spectro_directory = "Test_200-3_spectrogram.set"
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(spectrogramdir, formula) = spectro_directory
Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(spectrogramdir, formula).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    For Each percentvol In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500").Cells
    If percentvol.value = "Percent Snapdown Voltage" Then
        percentvol(1, 5).value = "110"
        percentvol(1, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next percentvol
 End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Only if there is some logical rule. I confess I don't really understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely improve this code with a Sub.

Here's how I would do that:

```vb
Sub HighlightIf(SearchRange As Range, Condition As String, OffsetColumn As Long, SetValue As Variant, Optional HighlightColor As Long = vbYellow)
    'Looping through each cell in the given search range
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In SearchRange.Cells
        'Skip cells containing worksheet errors like #DIV/0! or #NAME?
        If Not IsError(Cell.Value) Then
            'Compare the cell value to the given search condition
            If Cell.Value = Condition Then
                'In the same row as this cell, move over a number of columns equal to OffsetColumn - 1
                'In that cell, enter the given value and then highlight it
                Cell(1, OffsetColumn).Value = SetValue
                Cell(1, OffsetColumn).Interior.Color = HighlightColor
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This works the same as your For Loop, you just need to tell it what to look for and what to fill into the highlighted cells. Using variables instead of hardcoded "95" or "98".

Here's how to use it in your code:

```vb
HighlightIf ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500"), "Percent Snapdown Voltage", 5, "110", vbYellow
```

I have gone ahead and refactored your code to use the sub as well as make use of `With` blocks to simplify some of the repeated lines. Once I did so, I noticed that the only thing changing in the If Statement is the output value (e.g. "95","98","110"), which means that it makes more sense to save the changing output value into a variable and then after the If Statement, use the variable as an argument in the sub.

```vb
Sub updateWD()
    Const HighlightCondition As String = "Percent Snapdown Voltage"

    With Worksheets(sysnum).Columns(specmin)
        .Cells(coherencelengrow) = coherencelength

        'needed to prevent from skipping over second row of wavelenght tuning range
        HighlightIf SearchRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500"), _
                    Condition:="Wavelength Range", _
                    OffsetColumn:=3, _
                    SetValue:=tuningrange

        .Cells(averagepowerrow) = Power
        .Cells(kclockdepthrow) = kclockdepth
        .Cells(kclockjitter) = kclockcount
        .Cells(kclockctrow) = kclockcount
        .Cells(sweeprterow) = sweeprate
        Union( _
            .Cells(coherencelengrow), _
            .Cells(averagepowerrow), _
            .Cells(kclockdepthrow), _
            .Cells(kclockjitter), _
            .Cells(kclockctrow), _
            .Cells(sweeprterow) _
        ).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
    
    Dim filename As String
    Dim spectro_directory As String
    Dim HighlightOthers As Boolean
    Dim HighlightValue As String
    
    If wsName = "AXP-3" Then
        Select Case sweeprate
        Case Is < 50
            HighlightValue = "95"
    
        Case 50
            filename = "Test_50-3"
            spectro_directory = "Test_50-3_spectrogram.set"
            HighlightValue = "98"
            HighlightOthers = True
            
        Case 100
            filename = "Test_100-3"
            spectro_directory = "Test_100-3_spectrogram.set"
            HighlightValue = "110"
            HighlightOthers = True
            
        Case 200
            filename = "Test_200-3"
            spectro_directory = "Test_200-3_spectrogram.set"
            HighlightValue = "110"
            HighlightOthers = True
        End Select
    
        If HighlightOthers Then
            With Worksheets(sysnum).Columns(Formula)
                .Cells(scopefile) = filename
                .Cells(scopefile).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                .Cells(spectrogramdir) = spectro_directory
                .Cells(spectrogramdir).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End With
        End If
        
        If HighlightValue <> "" Then
            HighlightIf SearchRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500"), _
                        Condition:=HighlightCondition, _
                        OffsetColumn:=5, _
                        SetValue:=HighlightValue
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the repeated edits, I just kept re-reading my answer and finding small areas that I wanted to improve. I'm done now, I'm finally happy with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, the line for "Wavelength Range" is skipping over the second row that is needed. There are two rows that have the value "Wavelength Range" in them and i need both to be highlighted

Comment: @resu I just noticed that the first for loop is (1, 3) and the others are (1, 5). I will correct this in my answer. Does this fix your issue?

Comment: I now get an error at `HighlightIf ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500"), "Wavelength Range", 3, tuningrange ` The error message is ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: @resu I updated my function as well, make sure you're using the updated function

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much. As you can tell I am new to VBA so making my code structure be efficient is a work in progress. Can you explain to me the `Union( _ .Cells(coherencelengrow), _
            .Cells(averagepowerrow), _
            .Cells(kclockdepthrow), _
            .Cells(kclockjitter), _
            .Cells(kclockctrow), _
            .Cells(sweeprterow) _
        ).Interior.Color = vbYellow` part please with comments at the lines, along with the Function highlightif I know it is changing the cell color but I dont know it entirely

Comment: @resu Sure! `Union` joins multiple ranges together into one object, like how you can use `Range("A1,A5")` to join "A1" and "A5" together. Since we want to apply the same effect `.Interior.Color = vbYellow` to all of those ranges, I thought it would be easier to join them together and do it all at once. This is also a tiny bit faster, since Excel tries to refresh the screen after any visual changes, this will only trigger 1 refresh, instead of a refresh for each cell.

Comment: And what does OffSetColumn and SetValue mean in the function? And for `If HighlightValue <> "" Then HighlightIf ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500"), HighlightCondition, 5, HighlightValue` I know it says If highlightvalue does not equal " "  blank then highlight column 5 values, but what is the blank?

Comment: @resu, I added comments into my function. Those two names are parameters of my function. They accept values as arguments when the function is called, and then those values are used in the function to calculate the output.

Comment: @Resu `HighlightValue <> ""` is because when the variable is initialized, it is empty. As an empty string, its value is `""`. If it has been filled with any value, it will be `<> ""`. So I am basically checking "Has it been filled with any value?". I need to check that because there is the case where `sweeprate` does not equal <50, 50, 100, 200. In that case, `HighlightValue` has not been filled with any value and would cause an error when given to the function.

Comment: What is the given search condition? Is it looking for the wsName?

Comment: @resu In your loops, you're looking for "Wavelength Range" or "Percent Snapdown Voltage". That is the value being entered into `Condition`

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. So if there were a case where sweeprate was say 201 then it would throw an error. Is there a way to write a line that says if sweeprate does not equal a case then msgbox "No sweeprate value"

Comment: Add a `Case` into the `Select Case` tree. `Case Else: MsgBox "No sweeprate value"`

Comment: Also is there any issue with having my variables be global?

Comment: @resu It might be my version of Excel but I don't have the keyword `Global`. If I wanted a variable to be shared with other functions, subs and code modules, I'd declare it with  [Public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/public-statement) like `Public sysrow As Integer`

Comment: Oh, okay I couldnt tell you what version of Excel I am running but I believe is it a newer version. Do you know from your background what the command IsError mean? Like for example from the code above if I wanted to search for wavelength range and I write `wavelengthrange = Application.Match("Wavelength Range", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B"),0)`  
                                                
`IsError(wavelengthrange)`

Comment: I am reviewing your code to see if I can understand everything completely, can you explain the last two lines in the function highlight regarding the OffsetColumn - what is the Offset Column?

Comment: @resu In your original code, when you found "Wavelength Range", you put a value into the cell in the same row but 2 columns over, and similarly when you found "Percent Snapdown Voltage", you put a value into a cell in the same row but 4 columns over. The `OffsetColumn` argument allows the code to specify how many columns to move over when pasting in the value. For the first one, it is 3 and then for the other ones it is 5, just like in your original code.

Comment: Correct, I understand up to that but then I get lost as there is not indication of moving over 3 or 5 columns so how does the code know for which parameter should be moved over to which column? Like for Percent Snapdown Voltage that was at 5, how does it know to match the 5 with that rather than the 3?

Comment: @resu In the first line `HighlightIf ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500"), "Wavelength Range", 3, tuningrange`, you can see that I have written 3. and in the second line  `HighlightIf ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500"), HighlightCondition, 5, HighlightValue` I have written 5. Its as simple as that.

Comment: @resu I think I understand where you're getting stuck, I will update my answer one more time, to expand the `HighlightIf` lines fully

Comment: Oh so you just got rid of the 3 entirely